# Play 2.4: invoke evolutions manually

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I need to run evolutions manually before my Play 2.4 application starts. I'm guessing that could be done either in `Build.scala` or `Global.scala`? So far from what I could find I was trying to make it work in `Global.scala`, but can't quite get there:

```
import play.api.{Application, GlobalSettings}
import play.db.evolutions.Evolutions

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

    override def beforeStart(app: Application) = {

        Evolutions.applyEvolutions() //requires play.db.Database to be passed, not sure how to get it

    }

}
```

Any advice appreciated.